# I want to display a JOptionPane user input box in my start method of Application class (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx, joptionpane

```
public class Matrices extends Application {
    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        String inputValue = JOptionPane.ShowInputDialogue("Enter a value: ");
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This runs the program infinitely and doesn't display the JOptionPane dialogue box to ask the user for input

Answer (score 3):

**Why you shouldn't use a `JOptionPane`**

Don't use a [`JOptionPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) in a JavaFX application.

`JOptionPane` is for the Swing library, not the JavaFX library.

Generally, you should not mix Swing and JavaFX code unless you have a really good reason for it, and even then you must be careful about how you manage the integration (e.g. thread management) to ensure the best outcome.

**Use a JavaFX Dialog**

Instead of `JOptionPane`, use a JavaFX [`Dialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) or [`Alert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Alert.html).

For your particular case, you are using the `JOptionPane` to gather input, so the equivalent JavaFX dialog for this is a [`TextInputDialog`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputDialog.html).

**Why your app doesn't exit**

As to why the application doesn't complete, see the [`Application`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/application/Application.html) documentation:

> Waits for the application to finish, which happens when either of the following occur:
>
> - the application calls Platform.exit()
> - the last window has been closed and the implicitExit attribute on Platform is true

As you never show a JavaFX window and close it and you never call `Platform.exit()`, the application never shuts down.

This issue doesn't arise when you show a `TextInputDialog`, because that is a JavaFX window.  After you enter a value and close the input dialog, the application will shut down automatically (if the dialog was the only window currently being shown for the application).

**Working Example**

Here is an example which uses `TextInputDialog` instead of `JOptionPane`:

[image: example image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Optional;

public class TextInputDialogExample extends Application {
    private Optional<String> getValueFromUser() {
        TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog("xyzzy");

        dialog.setTitle("Value Input");
        dialog.setHeaderText("Enter a value:");
        dialog.setContentText("Value:");

        return dialog.showAndWait();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Optional<String> value = getValueFromUser();

        value.ifPresent(System.out::println);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```